# Same WM_CLASS, separate launcher icons

Tags: icons, launcher, window

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I have several emacs windows open. Some of them are grouped together in the launcher but one of them shows as a separate icon. Running
"xprop WM_CLASS" for each of the windows shows that they all have the same WMCLASS:
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs"

What could be the issue that causes the separate icons and how can it be fixed?